# How to use mmap(2) to modify a parent's environment from a child process?

Tags: c, unix, process, environment-variables, memory-address

I'm attempting to have a child process modify the environment list of its parent process. 
Searching around pointed towards mmap(2) as the way to go,

```
void *mmap(void *start, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);
```

but I'm lost as to how to actually implement this. Any ideas?

Comment: don't force; cooperate. Use IPC to signal the parent of the desired change (e.g. a pipe back to the parent, message queue, what not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot affect the environment of the parent process

Normally you can affect the environment of only the current process and any child processes that you invoke.